# I want to have Order ID for Strapi Ecommerce

Tags: nuxt.js, strapi

I'm using Nuxt.v2 and Strapi.v4 without module, everythings works fine but in my ecommerce project I want to have Order ID same as other ecommerce websites, for example: Order ID 1000 and increment that ID start from 1000 per purchase means other user purchased Order ID going to 1001, is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily what you want, but if it is your intention to hide how many orders you actually got this way, you could look into the new custom field feature (requires strapi 4.4.0+). There already is an UUID field that uses unique identifiers.

You can find it on the strapi market: [UUID field](https://market.strapi.io/plugins/@bn-digital-strapi-plugin-field-uuid)